# Crear dataframe Python desde info de una API

Tags: python

Soy nueva en programación en Python y tengo un problema al guardar la información de una API en un dataframe, ya obtuve el json pero me da error al guardar del json a dataframe.
¿Alguien podría ayudarme?

Comment: Hola Alejandra, bienvenida a [es.so]. Te recomiendo pasarte por [tour] y [ask] para conocer por encima el funcionamiento del sitio y cómo realizar buenas preguntas. En cuanto a tu pregunta, si no aportas ninguna información como el **código que usas** para construir el DataFrame a partir del json, ni aportas el **error o problema concreto** ni tampoco el JSON o un [mcve], va a ser muy difícil que te podamos ayudar.  ¿Lo que tienes es una cadena/archivo JSON o un diccionario Python construido a partir de ese JSON? Porque no es lo mismo, `pandas.read_json` /  `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` ...

Answer (score 0):

Como recomendación sería bueno que pusieras el código que has usado y el error que recibes (o un ejemplo que represente el error).

Como eres nueva supongo que tu error será algo muy básico, deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd 
pd.read_json("C:/mi_usuario/mi_caperta/tu_archivo.json")
```

- La primera linea nos traemos la librería pandas, para poder utilizarla y le ponemos el alias pd
- Usamos la función de pandas "read_json" y tienes que poner **entre comillas** la siguiente información:

  1. El directorio donde se encuentra tu archivo json.
  2. El nombre del archivo incluyendo su extensión.
  3. Si eres **usuario de windows** tienes que cambiar las contrabarras (\) por la barra (/), si no lo haces te dará error.

Espero haber sido de ayuda :)